# Where is "File Explorer" in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I wanted to browse files, export databases, etc. on Android Emulator in Eclipse, I used File Explorer.

I cannot find this tool in IntelliJ and it seems that Android does not have its own GUI tool.

Does IntelliJ have this tool or I'd have to use adb console tool?

Comment: Some people arriving here might be looking for this: [Locate current file in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij) (happened to me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although, IntelliJ does not have the File Explorer (like Eclipse has), we can use Android SDK native tool DDMS. You can find it in /tools/ folder. Start it, let it connect to Emulator's process and then open its File Explorer (Device/File Explorer). It has the same functionalities like Eclipse's plug-in.

Comment: @Eugene I agree on this. Google time should make it better. But I don't think they plan doing it soon.

Comment: I think, that JetBrains should keep a steady pace of that features. All in all IntelliJ is their main product.

Answer (score 9):

There is a FileExplorer in IntelliJ.

You cand find it via the IntelliJ toolbar:  `Tools -> Android -> Monitor`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find "Monitor" there.

Comment: Try "Android Device Monitor" in the same menu.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such tool in IDEA.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder. Every day I seem to ask things like "where is that and that tool in IntelliJ". The reason for this is that I cannot find on your site any FAQ document which will lead Eclipse developers into IntelliJ (explain what's missing from Eclipse and suggest work-around). So far IntelliJ lacks lot of Eclipse's tools and I think that many developers would welcome such document.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There **is** a file browser in Intellij, and it can be used to browse both local and remote file systems.  It is called **Browse Remote Host**, which is a bit confusing, but it can be used to browse the local file system as follows:

Add a "server", denoting the local file system you want to browse:
Tools → Deployment → Configuration... → Add (green + sign)
Name: <name that will appear in popup menu in the browser window>
Type: Local or mounted folder
→ OK
Folder: <select the top directory of the file system you want to browse>
→ OK
Now, open the browser window as follows:
Tools → Deployment → Browse Remote Host
The browser window will appear at the right side of the IDE.

Comment: However it's not ideal - when you open a file through this tool, it's treated as a remote file, and when you edit it, its content is not automatically saved on disk, rather you need to use a button 'Upload Current Remote File'. So it's not behaving same as editing other project files.

Answer (score 3):

To tie a few of these answers together, there is a standalone tool at:

```
/android-sdk/tools/monitor.bat
```

You can launch it from IntelliJ using

```
Tools -> Android -> Monitor
```

Or Eclipse using

```
Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS
```

Either way, you get the exact same tool.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Android->Monitor in your Intellij IDE.

Answer (score 0):

askmo, maybe Intelliji IDEA commander tool will be helpful to you,
Try it in Window -> Tools Windows -> Commander

webhelp: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/commander-tool-window.html

Comment: There is a better tool. I will name it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its just improved over time over what others have discussed here, but I really like using DDMS with IntelliJ.  I access it by: `Tools->Android->DDMS`.

I access the file explorer by clicking on my device in the top left hand window, then selecting `Device->File Explorer`.