# How to make Scroll From Source feature always enabled?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to enable "Scroll from source" in IntelliJ IDEA so it is always on, meaning if you open any file it is automatically shown in Project view, likewise it is made in Eclipse?

There is a possibility to click the button in Project to find chosen file, but it is annoying to click it each time you open another file.

Comment: Now it's called "Always Select Opened File". In case someone else stares at the IntelliJ project menu for minutes like me.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You can check `Autoscroll from source` in setting for project pane (in the lastest version is probably different icon)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  This has been my biggest problem with moving from Eclipse to IntelliJ

Comment: @EatatJoes -- in VS go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General and enable the checkbox "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer".

Comment: "Autoscroll to Source" makes sense to me (I think), what does "Autoscroll from Source" mean?

Comment: Autoscroll To Source means a single click in the project tree opens/jumps to that code window.
Autoscroll From Source means when you switch to a different code window the project tree will jump to/highlight that file.

Comment: not sure if I'm the only one, but those two autoscroll features don't always work.

Comment: For me this solution only works when I switch between file tabs. When I open a new file using Open File och Open Class nothing happens!

Comment: @Gubatron I encountered same issue. I had pending plug-in installs. I reset layout defaults and once I installed pending updates and had it restart then it worked. Previously just restarting editor did not work.

Answer (score 36):

Unfortunately this setting must be ticked every time you open or create a new project.

If you would like this setting to persist between projects, you can use this plugin:

[AutoScroll Save IntelliJ Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7575?pr=idea)

Disclaimer: I am the plugin author.

Comment: This plugin fixed our problem, the detail step I use is : 'Toggle AutoScroll From Source' -> 'AutoScroll Save' from enter action by Ctrl+Shift+A.

Comment: Should be enabled by default!

Comment: Cool. This plugin also works in `IntelliJ 2019.3.1`, where the options "Autoscroll from/to source" have been removed from UI for some reason.

Comment: they were renamed as was suggested in an answer by @Eric_Tan

Answer (score 15):

From version 2019.3.1, the name of the options have been changed as below:

Autoscroll to Source -> Open Files with Single Click

Autoscroll from Source -> Always Select Opened File

The credit will go to [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006983339-Autoscroll-to-Source). Hope it helps.

Comment: After reading this answer, the new wording seems more user-friendly. But as a long time Intellij user, I was specifically looking for the familiar "scroll from source" and my mind basically just skimmed past this. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 2019.3 and I could not find the gear icon, or Autoscroll or Open Files in the Settings.

Here's what I did instead, after 30 minutes of searching.

1. Right click on the Project
2. Enable "Open Files with Single Click"

[image]