# What is the use of autoscroll to source and and autoscroll from source features in Intellij IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, autoscroll

I was looking for how to show the open files in project view and found theses two features, I want to know what does the above mentioned features do?

Comment: Pressing F1 and searching for autoscroll would be easier than asking this question.

Comment: Autoscroll to/from source is a feature across all JetBrains IDEs that has never worked reliably, despite being one of the easiest features to get right. So I can understand why you may not see it doing anything despite enabling it.

Comment: Related thread - [How to make Scroll From Source feature always enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11051692/465053)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Explaining this simply,

**Autoscroll to Source**
Whenever you click on a file name in the Explorer Window, the file will be brought into focus on the editor. If the file is not open, it will be opened.

**Autoscroll from Source**
If you select a file in the Editor, that fill will be scrolled to and highlighted in the Project Explorer.

Comment: Now, this should be the accepted answer. Concise, to the point and easy to understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

From the manual,

**Autoscroll to Source**

> If this option is on, IntelliJ IDEA automatically navigates from a file (or a class member) selected in the Project tool window to the corresponding source file (or its fragment) in the editor. If the corresponding file is not currently open, it will open automatically.

**Autoscroll from Source**

> If this option is on, IntelliJ IDEA automatically navigates from a file in the editor to the corresponding node (file, class, field, method, etc.) in the Project tool window.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-tool-window.html