# Where is the "Scroll from Source" option?

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm both at work (Ubuntu) and at home (Windows 7). One thing I've been missing on the version I have at home is the "Scroll from Source" button, seen below:

[image]

It's completely absent in my home version. I've looked for it, but all I get are results for plugins that help set a hotkey for "Scroll from Source", reports about it not working properly, or (seemingly) unrelated things, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051692/how-to-make-scroll-from-source-feature-always-enabled/26360547).

Is this button a plugin? Or does it come with the base installation? All I want to do is jump directly to the file I have currently open, which the button in the screenshot usually does in the version I have at work. How can I enable it? Or is it specific to the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is hidden if "Autoscroll from source" is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems in the most recent versions they have the naming of that functionality. The button itself is there but has different title:
[image]