# PhpStorm "synchronize editor with views"

Tags: netbeans, ide, phpstorm

I recently switched from Netbeans to PhpStorm.

Only thing I'm missing and can't seem to find is the function Netbeans calls "Synchronize editor with views".
This function highlights the file you have open in your editor tab in the file tree browser.

I find this very handy in projects with a lot of files such as a Drupal or Magento project, when switching between tabs. Makes it alot faster to find related files to the one you're editing.

The question is, obviously, does PhpStorm have it and where do I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 options:

`Alt+F1` (Select target), choose 'Project view'

or enable `'Autoscroll from source'` option in the Project view

See [Locate current file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)

Comment: Autoscroll from source is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: There's also a plugin to remember this setting called `Autoscroll Save`.