# shortcut in Android Studio to locate the current editing src file

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

Do you know how to check the location of current editing file in the project tree panel  (the very left panel of the Android Studio), except manually. (The worst case is that all the folders there are collapsed)

The Navigate->Class shortcut can show me the src file in edit panel (central panel) quickly. Then I want to know the src file's logic location in project tree (left panel), so that I can add some new files in the same package quickly. (e.g. right-click the package and add new Class).

Currently, I have to expand the project tree and find it folder by folder.

Actually, in Xcode there is such a shortcut named "Reveal in Project Navigate"

What a convenient way it is.

I wonder whether this is also supported in Android studio.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locate current file in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)

Comment: It's exactly much the same as in IntelliJ, so check out this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij

Answer (score 296):

You can use the **Scroll from Source** button in the Project Toolbar in the left of Android Studio.

[image: locate]

Another solution is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. You can also read [Locate current file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij) for more answers.

Comment: keyboard shortcut: `Alt-F1, Enter`

Comment: To be noted that clicking the button did nothing for me, but enabling `Autoscroll from Source` (right click the empty area to the left of said button)  now selects the opened file in the tree. Also, after enabling it, the button is removed.

Comment: `Alt-F1` menu is a lifesaver, thanks @wal. `Alt-F1 8` to reveal in finder :)

Answer (score 49):

Just enable the following option!

[image]

Comment: This is a far better answer than the top one, though technically it isn't exactly what the OP asked. Not sure why it's getting so few upvotes.

Comment: I don't have this menu in the latest Android Studio, but right-clicking on "Android" and checking "Always Select Opened File" did the trick for me.

Comment: I agree, this is the better long term solution. I love this feature in VS code and am happy to see it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 20):

In Android Studio 4 it is now `Always Select Opened File` under the Settings menu in the project view.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

For automatic scrolling, you can do following:

You need to ensure `Autoscroll to Source`  and `Autoscroll from source` is enabled.

[image: auto scroll]

Whenever you change the file the Project tree will be highlighted according.

I have observed some slowness and lag if project size is big(several modules or huge code base) and you use short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to navigate to a class.

So the alternative would be to either to click following icon:
[image: icon]

**OR**

Use keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> **or**  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: What if I don't have icon?(full clean reinstall of OS + AS Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch somehow lost it. is it possible to make it back?(Autoscroll options work)

Answer (score 7):

You can add shortcut (keymap) to "reveal current editing file in project explorer" command.

1. Press `Ctrl + Alt + S`, for Windows user, to open Settings
2. Select `Keymap` on the sidebar
3. Find the command using search box, type this into it: `select in project view`
4. Right click the result then select Add Keyboard Shortcut
5. Type any keyboard combination you want, for example, me prefer shortcut `Ctrl + K` to reveal current editing file on project explorer
6. Click OK button. It will prompt you to remove keyboard shortcut you typed from existing command, so just click Remove button.

I'm new to android development. I used to code in Sublime Text 3. One of first thing I do to make android development feels more enjoyable is binding all shortcut I used in Sublime Text 3 to Android Studio. Now, it feels like home :)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i searched.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac users: `Option`+`fn`+`F1`, then `Enter`.

Answer (score 6):

**Android Studio 3.6.3 (April 2020)**

Go to Preferences > Keymap & search for "Select in Project View" and assign your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You might want to clarify how to go to keybindings

Comment: To go to keybindings, open Android Studio -> Preferences (Cmd + , on a mac) -> Keymap

Answer (score 2):

Under options menu, select Auto scroll from Source

Answer (score 2):

open `pref` -> `Keymap`, then search '***select file in project view***', not '***select opened file***'.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate -> Select In.. -> Project View -> Project