# intelliJ idea show active panel in Project window

Tags: intellij-idea

As the title,
I want to use compare function.

Compare files func need to select one file in Project window, then I can use "Compare file with editor".

There's a problem :
I need to find the file step by step by clicking folder in Project window.

Is there anyway to show active panel in Project window quickly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking here.  So you want to use the compare function - which compare function?  If you have a VCS that supports branches, like Git, Mercurial, or Subversion, you have the option to compare the current code with a branch.  If you want to compare some content from the clipboard with a file, you can do that too.  Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/exuMbpF.png
I can't upload imagine in stackoverflow.
please click above link.
Hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused.  I understand that you have a file highlighted, but I don't know if they're the same file.  Not just that, but it *does* look like you have a VCS configured.  Do you just want to see the Changes menu at the bottom (CTRL + 9 or Command + 9)?

Comment: Alt + F1
That's what I mean ..
Sorry, broken English.
Thx for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or click on that symbol in the project panel:

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)