# Shortcut for locate current file in Project Explorer in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I read this post:

[Locate current file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)

Still the problem is that I do not want to have Autosccroll from Source enabled because my Project Explorer will be jumping up and down. Rather I need a shortcut to locate the current file in the Project explorer when I  need to. ALT + F1 does work but you need to select from a context menu where you would like the file to be shown. In Resharper for example the shortcut is ALT+SHIFT+L but I am not able to find such a shorcut in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this action in IntelliJ IDEA other than Alt-F1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way of doing this.

I can think of 4 options:

1. You can install the plugin 'Scroll From Source' which will allow you set such a shortcut in the keymap settings (Default: <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Use the target symbol in the project explorer, no shortcut but is default option.
3. Get used to having to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Record a macro for the above key presses but this may be unreliable. You could then assign a shortcut key to play this marco.