# is there a shortcut key for quick locate the file on navi bar in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I can not find the intellij shortcut key for scroll from source  ,which is to locate the file in navi bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locate current file in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no key directly for that action. It is not in the find action dialog nor in keymap.
There is a [IntelliJ Idea Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7606) Scroll From Source, which enables you to bind keyboard shortcut to that feature.

---

Alternatively, you can achieve similar behavior by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note that you can enable automatic scroll to source feature.

[image]