# PyCharm - how to sync project view with editor

Tags: pycharm

I'm quite new to PyCharm and I can't find a way to sync the project view (the one that contains all files in project) with the editor view (the one that contains the currently opened files). In Eclipse there's a simple [Link with Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVgUz.png) icon that does that. I'm sure there's a way to do that in PyCharm but I just can't find it...

Comment: I may be wrong, but as Jetbrain's documentation is quite good, if you can't find it in there it probably won't be a default setting to toggle.

Comment: Try to use `Scroll from Source`, answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij) could help you

Comment: Great thanks for you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make sure "**Autoscroll to Source**" and "**Autoscroll from Source**" are both checked. You can find them under the [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIil2.png) drop down menu in the "Project" pane.

See in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXSgu.png) how it should look like