# How to find the Package in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and I just want to know is there a way we can find the Class or Package location in Intellij Idea

I have 2 projects loaded in Intellij and both projects have many Packages
How can i find the accurate location of Class which is open?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locate current file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij)

Comment: Yeah , Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `Alt+F1` shortcut to navigate to the location of Class which is open.

If your `project` window can't see, you can use `Alt+1` to open the project window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a crosshair icon at the top of the project window that allows you to quickly move to the class location within the project tree.
[image: crosshair]